# Grant role to exec stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a proxy user that I'm trying to add to a role that can execute all stored procedures. Using other StackOverflow posts, I have been able to put together this script

```
USE abc

Create ROLE db_exec
go

GRANT EXECUTE TO db_exec
go

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_exec', 'abc_user'
go
```

When I try to run my stored procedures though, I'm still getting this error, per my error handling.

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_OACreate', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.

What can I do to let `abc_user` execute `sp_OACreate`?

Comment: *sp_OACreate: Requires membership in the sysadmin fixed server role.*

Comment: @AlexK. I have added the user to sysadmin and verified with `select is_srvrolemember('sysadmin', 'abc_user')` returns `1` but I'm still getting the same error, any ideas?

Comment: It also requires that ole automation be enabled, you can get this error in that instance as well.  Finally.....  try to avoid ole automation in SQL Server.  It's a DB server, not an APP server.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In addition to being in sysadmin role,  you also need to grant execute permission on the master database where those procedures actually reside

```
use master
go

grant exec on sp_OACreate to abc_user
GO
```

After you run that you can verify with the following that you have permission to execute the procedure

```
SELECT * 
FROM master.sys.database_permissions [dp] 
JOIN master.sys.system_objects [so] ON dp.major_id = so.object_id
JOIN master.sys.sysusers [usr] ON 
     usr.uid = dp.grantee_principal_id AND usr.name = 'abc_user'
WHERE permission_name = 'EXECUTE' AND so.name = 'sp_OACreate'
```

Comment: If you ran into "Cannot find the user 'abc_user', because it does not exist or you do not have permission." when on database master, the workaround is to create your user for the login in master too: "create user abc_user for login abc_user;"

Answer (score 6):

The answer given works, however, we generally try to not give the sysadmin permission to *any* user whenever possible.  In this case I have found to run `sp_OACreate` you don't actually need the sysadmin role.

I ran the following:

```
use master
grant exec on sp_OACreate to yourSecObject
grant exec on sp_OADestroy to yourSecObject  --Optional
grant exec on sp_OAMethod to yourSecObject
```

For my purposes I required a cleanup step so the user required both Create and Destroy.

I hope this helps anyone who wants to give the ability to run these procedures but does not want the user to have full DB access to all other databases on the server.

-Scott

Answer (score 2):

In case of the following errors:

```
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_cmdshell', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_OACreate', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_OAMethod', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_OAMethod', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_OAMethod', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_OAGetProperty', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_OAGetProperty', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_OADestroy', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.
```

### Enable the xp_cmdshell procedure

it was probably already be executed at this point, so this is for reference only:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

### Allow the user to execute the stored procedures

```
use [master]
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON [sys].[xp_cmdshell] TO [DOMAIN\username];
GRANT EXECUTE ON [sys].[sp_OACreate] TO [DOMAIN\username];
GRANT EXECUTE ON [sys].[sp_OADestroy] TO [DOMAIN\username];
GRANT EXECUTE ON [sys].[sp_OAGetErrorInfo] TO [DOMAIN\username];
GRANT EXECUTE ON [sys].[sp_OAGetProperty] TO [DOMAIN\username];
GRANT EXECUTE ON [sys].[sp_OAMethod] TO [DOMAIN\username];
GRANT EXECUTE ON [sys].[sp_OAStop] TO [DOMAIN\username];
GRANT EXECUTE ON [sys].[sp_OASetProperty] TO [DOMAIN\username];
GO
```

### Check if the execute permissions are set

```
SELECT * 
FROM master.sys.database_permissions [dp] 
JOIN master.sys.system_objects [so] ON dp.major_id = so.object_id
JOIN master.sys.sysusers [usr] ON usr.uid = dp.grantee_principal_id AND usr.name = 'DOMAIN\username'
WHERE permission_name = 'EXECUTE' 
AND (so.name = 'xp_cmdshell'
  OR so.name = 'sp_OACreate'
  OR so.name = 'sp_OADestroy'
  OR so.name = 'sp_OAGetErrorInfo'
  OR so.name = 'sp_OAGetProperty'
  OR so.name = 'sp_OAMethod'
  OR so.name = 'sp_OAStop'
  OR so.name = 'sp_OASetProperty')
```

Answer (score 1):

The procs are located in master > Programmability > Extended Stored Procedures > System Extended Stored Procedures if that helps.